# What is a Royal Word™?

Tags: language, computer-puzzle

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

$
\begin{gather*}
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\textbf{Royal Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not Royal Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad\ }
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[lightblue]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{46px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  YOUNG}&\text{       OLD}\\ \hline
\text{  FIRE}&\text{       WATER}\\ \hline
\text{  COW}&\text{       GOAT}\\ \hline
\text{  WORLDBUILDING}&\text{       PUZZLING}\\ \hline
\text{  BANANA}&\text{       APPLE}\\ \hline
\text{  AUDIO}&\text{       VIDEO}\\ \hline
\text{  DECIMAL}&\text{       BINARY}\\ \hline
\text{  LAWYER}&\text{       ATTORNEY}\\ \hline
\text{  VIOLIN}&\text{       FIDDLE}\\ \hline
\text{  MUSHROOM}&\text{       FUNGUS}\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}
\end{gather*}$

CSV:

```
Royal Word™, Not a Royal Word™
YOUNG, OLD
FIRE, WATER
COW, GOAT
WORLDBUILDING, PUZZLING
BANANA, APPLE
AUDIO, VIDEO
DECIMAL, BINARY
LAWYER, ATTORNEY
VIOLIN, FIDDLE
MUSHROOM, FUNGUS
```

What makes a Royal Word™ a Royal Word™?

Some pairs are synonyms, others are antonyms. Some pairs are completely unrelated. So what is a Royal Word™?

Hint 1:

> You can only deduce this with the words in all capitals with no spaces.

Hint 2:

> The solution is **unrelated** to the phonemes of the words and the letter orders of the words.

Hint 3:

> The answer can only be found using a method that makes it impossible to deduce the original words without trial and error.

Hint 4:

> The answer uses a method that **is** very difficult to do by hand. Computers will aid you in the process.

Hint 5:

> The answer is related to the first digit of the number generated by the method.

Hint 6:

> 50% of the possible first digits values of the number generated by the method result in Royal Words™, 50% do not.

Comment: Could you please rewrite my words into a table to help the blind?

Comment: Done :) I’ve put it in a CSV but can put it in one of the fancier Mathjax ones you might have seen in previous questions if needed

Comment: I like a Mathjax to replace my image.

Comment: Replaced, if someone a lil bit better at Mathjax can fix the blue box that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: "Royal" in trademark?! According to trademarkroom dot com, "Consent can be obtained from the Lord Chamberlain’s office at Buckingham Palace, London, SW1A 1AA" :) That's for the UK only, of course.

Comment: @NickRice, where I live, “royal” is a public domain term. It can be used freely since there is no monarchy here.

Comment: @galactic_analyzer It was meant as a joke. Not a very good attempt, I admit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All words depends on:

> Hash algorithm SHA-256. If first (in binary) number is 1 -> it is Royal word, otherwise not.
>   It has 50% chance for every string that first number could be 1, and 50% that it is 0.

For example:

> YOUNG is `90008a2bee7e9adbf273a4c637683197878bed1e48a8b8c59ef4e9d95d0069eb`, first number is > 7, in binary 1001. So it is Royal
>  OLD is `099d90cbee62f89e6478e153eb3240efcbe4ac2231bedc3e84549bbeaaba87e8`, where 0 in binary is 0000. So it is not Royal
>  VIDEO is `65b2f9ec331fc7267fd32f75f18e799a3a9217765108226c99b6638ebfb36f84`, where 6 in binary is 0110. So it is not Royal

You can check for example [here](https://xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator)

As a sidenote:

> A hint by the author was presumably that SHA resembles the royal title Shah.